# Ubuntu 22.04 looks weird upon upgrading from 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, desktop-environments, do-release-upgrade

After upgrading from 20.04, my Ubuntu looks weird and acts strange

Official looks

[image]

Mine

[image]

Even the search bar always show nothing...

[image]

Every hotkey requires ctrl and windows key. For example maximize the window:

Previously: windows key + up

Currently: ctrl + windows key + up

Comment: Did you install the unity desktop at some point?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi YESSSSSSSSS. Thank you so much

Comment: Logout and choose Gnome/ Ubuntu while loging in.

Comment: Yeah, I just purge unity and then reboot. Everything is perfect now. Thanks a lot. I installed unity by an accident. While trying to fix "blue background, no icons, no interaction".